# Check if document exists in collection with Mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to to check if email already exists in 'users' collection:

I have this model:

```
const isEmailExists = async (value) => {
    const res = await User.countDocuments({ email: value });
    return res > 0;
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate(value) {
            isEmailExists(value).then(res => {
                if (res) {
                    throw new Error('Email already exists');
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And I use post method with express router:

```
router
    .route('/register')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(publicDirPath + '/auth/register.html');
    })
    .post(async (req, res) => {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        try {
            const saveUser = await user.save();
            res.send(saveUser);
        } catch (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
    });
```

For some reason, it does not work and the user is been added anyway..

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if one document with a certain entry/value exists you can do this :

```js
function emailExists(value) {
    User.findOne({email: value}).then((err, user) => !!user)
}
```

Comment: now working. I did not asked about the function, but how to handle the promise in the validate and model methods ..

Comment: I dont think this is a good method to check if it exists because it will return the full document even tho you just want to know if it exists or not.